# Centering an Image

Tags: html, css, image

So this is probably an easy answer, but my image which is supposed to be sitting in the middle of the page is *slightly* off and it's irritating me a lot.

HTML:

```html
</section>

<section class="img_section">
<div>
  <img src="images/menu.jpg" alt="menu" align="center"> 


  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```html
img section{
 float:center;
 text-align:center;
}
```

I've tried removing float, and taking it out of a section entirely, but it *won't* budge.

Any help would be amazing

Comment: Just FYI there is no such thing as float: center. It's only left, right or none.

Answer (score 2):

there's no such thing as `float: center;`
also `img section` doesn't style image within section.
you could try either:
1:

```
img {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

2:

```
section div {
text-align: center;
}
section div img {
display: inline-block;
}
```

depending on your other styles

Comment: what other styles do you hjave for .img_section ?

Comment: img section{
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}
section img {
display: inline-block;
}

Comment: does your section have any width defined?

Comment: It should be working, so maybe any other css styling is adding either a padding or a margin to the image, if you are using chrome browser left click on the image and select "inspect", then in the left window all the rules applied to the image will popup, check if there is a margin or a padding, also a link will help us to find the error

Comment: @AnaG if it doesn't, that means it's width is set by it's children. How do you then expect the image to be centered? Can you replicate your example on fiddle?

Comment: you constantly say `img section { ... }`, don't you mean `.img_section { ... }`? (not the dot and the underscore)

Answer (score 1):

This is simple to answer.

```css
#div1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
</section>

<section class="img_section">
  <div id="div1">
    <img src="images/menu.jpg" alt="menu" align="center">
   </div>
</section>
```

The `text-align: center;` property is going to make all the elements inside the `div` centered. Also, it is better if you select the `div` with a specific class or ID. This is going to go on all `div` elements on the page.

Comment: this solution will center all the text and images of the entire page, you should be more specific adding the .img_section class

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It is better if the `div` has a specific class or id before styling it.

Answer (score 0):

try in css:

```
.img_section img{
    text-align:center;
}
```

html:

```
<section class="img_section">
    <img src="images/menu.jpg" alt="menu" align="center">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is much more simple. just include **center** tag as

```
<center>
  <section>
   <div>
        <img src="images/menu.jpg" alt="menu" align="center"> 
   </div>
  </section>
</center>
```

Comment: The `center` tag has been deprecated for several years now. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: Yup. It works in Chrome. How ever I am sorry and thanks for sharing this information

Answer (score 0):

I like to use

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

for centering